# batch add images to mp3 files

Tags: id3v2, eyed3

I have a few mp3 files:

- first file.mp3
- second file.mp3
- third file.mp3

and artwork for them:

- first file.png
- second file.png
- third file.png

How do I add images as tags to mp3 files (1 to 1; 2 to 2; 3 to 3) in batch mode?

Answer (score 0):

Using `eyeD3` maybe you need a loop:

```
n=1; while [ $n -le 3 ]; do
    eyeD3 add-image $n.image.png:ILLUSTRATION $n.audio.mp3
    let n++
done
```

Note that the name of your files should be numbered

```
1.image.png, 2.image.png, 1.audio.mp3 ..... ect.
```